# Keep object state between OnGet and OnPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have registered a service in my `Startup` class, initialize my `UserService`'s properties in one of my page's `OnGet()` method, then calling `OnPost()`, makes lose of my properties. What do I make wrong? What would be the solution?

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //...
  services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
}
```

**My UserService class**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
  // ...
  private ApplicationUser _appUser;
  public void Initalize(ClaimsPrincipal claim)
  {
    var curretUserId = claim.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    _appUser =  _userManager.FindByIdAsync(curretUserId).Result;
  }
}
```

**One of my Page's back-end**

```
[Authorize]
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
  // ....
  private readonly IUserService _userService;
  public CreateModel( // ... dependencies,
                     IUserService userService)
  {
    _userService = userService;
  }

  public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
  {
    // ...
    _userService.Initalize(User);
    // everything are good here, _appUser is initalized and I have all my properties are initialized
  }
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
  {
    // _userService._appUser is NULL here. Why?
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Updated my answer with a second approach.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your UserService is recreated on every request.

UPDATE

Because my first answer did not, by some unknown reason, solve OPs problem, here is a second suggestion.

Add this to `PageModel` class (may be of type int if that is more suitable)

```
[BindProperty]
public string SelectedUserId { get; set; }
```

Change get- and post methods like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
{
  ...
  SelectedUserId = ... some value
  ...
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
   ... use SelectedUserId to get user to work with
   
   ...
}
```

The clue here is to save SelectedUserId between the requests inside the form as a hidden.

If that is not sufficient, multiple properties from object may be serialized as multiple hiddens in form, and deserialized in PageModel class.

To take this to the max level, object may implement ToString, store object string in a single hidden in form, and deserialize object on post request.

Unfortunately, we don't have any markup available in the question to work with, so I left that part out.

Comment: I have multiple methods and multiple properties in my UserService, but not included every line of code of my class. This is not a solution for my problem.

Comment: At least you got an explanation for why current solution doesn't work :-)